# C++ Stream serialization

Tags: c++, serialization

Currently I'm trying to implement some kind of object stream, similar to the structure that exists in java.

Using the ["Stream Socket API" by Rob Tougher](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/socketsC++/sockets.html) it's easy to use the stream insertion `operator<<`.

This would lead to the problem that every serializable object would require every single class to overload the same operators in the same manner.

Example:

```
class A
{
    protected:
        int value;

    friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& in, const A& obj );
};

class B
{
    protected:
        float value;

    friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& in, const B& obj );
};

ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& in, const A& obj)
{
    return (in << obj.value);
}

ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& in, const B& obj)
{
    return (in << obj.value);
}
```

Well. That's easy and works. Now I'm thinking about whether it's somehow possible to ease and automate the process of this serialization.

I already thought back and forth how this could be done using some combination with both, templates and macros. Using `typeid` (RTTI) would partially work, but this fails at the point where you would need to cast a value in a type when only the typeid is known. Which simply isn't possible.

Is there really no other solution that to simply let the user implement each and every `operator<<` ? Am I thinking too far and the solution is quite easy?

Otherwise, in all ways I've tried and thought through, the problem ends at where I need to reinstanciate an object when the classname isn't known at compile-time.

Any idea is appreciated.

PS: Using `fwrite(item, sizeof(item), 1, handle);` isn't the solution as well. Not platform independent at all.

Comment: `boost::serialize` already exists.

Comment: Although I didn't want to use boost, I'll take a look at it. However we anyway want to implement it on our own...

Comment: @Atmocreations: I think you'd need reflection (not supported in C++) to implement automatic serialization.

Comment: Note that there are issues with the ASCII representation of a floating point value. "0.49" and "4.900000095E-1" yield the same bits when converted to float.

Comment: @Emile: Yes. That entirely automatic serialization isn't possible without reflection is clear and not what I expect. But I would like to automate the process the best possible.

Comment: @Tomalak, Emile: It's not only because we need to have the functionality, but also we'd like to make our own reflections about this stuff. The main reason is educational and we thought to build such a thing on our own. That's all.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use boost::serialize because you'd like to do this yourself for educational purposes, I would suggest you review boost library because it solved just about every question you have posted here.  Build a test project and walk through the code.  And since there's no reflection in C++, there's no simple answer.  Even in boost::serialize each class must have a custom method that does serialization, but they simplify the amount of code you have to enter by using macros.  They also have a solution for creating objects not known at compile type by using global class maps.

Comment: @Atmocreations: Ah, well if it's educational then that's fine. :) I suggest taking a look through `boost::serialize`'s API; it should give more than a few hints on how they do it, which looks similar-ish to the approach you're considering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java serialization relies on reflection to automatically discover and serialize class fields. In C++, your options are:

1. Write input and output functions manually for each class. boost::serialization uses this approach.
2. Declare serializable entities in a separate language and compile that language to C++ with automatically generated in/out operators. CORBA, protobuf, ZeroC ICE and thrift all use this approach.
3. In theory you could probably use C++ itself as the definition language, but C++ is hard enough to parse that I don't know of any serialization frameworks that attempt that. Perhaps now that clang can actually compile real programs, someone may try.
4. Declare every serializable entity using macros and compile every header twice, with different macro definitions (once to declare classes, once to create serializers). I've seen it done in closed-source code I had to maintain and the result was extremely ugly and inflexible, so I'd advise against it.

Comment: good answer. method 1 and 4 isn't a good solution. i thought about doing something which uses method 2. thanks!